# Erro no php na minha sintaxe

Tags: php, mysql

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''loja_categorias' ORDER BY id DESC'

Os codigos a baixo

```
<?php
class Site extends BD{
    public function getdate(){
        $data = getdate();
        $diaHoje = date('d');
        $mesgetdate = $date['mon'];
        /*$array_meses = array(1 => "Janeiro", 2 => "Fevereiro", 3 => "Março", 4 => "Abril", 5 => "Maio", 6 => "Junho", 
                               7 => "Julho", 8 => "Agosto", 9 => "Setembro", 10 => "Outubro", 11 => "Novembro", 12 => 'Dezembro');*/

        $meses = array (1 == "Janeiro", 2 => "Fevereiro", 3 => "Março", 4 => "Abril", 5 => "Maio", 6 => "Junho", 
                        7 => "Julho", 8 => "Agosto", 9 => "Setembro", 10 => "Outubro", 11 => "Novembro", 12 => "Dezembro");
        $horaAgora = date('H:i');
        $anoAtual = date('Y');

        return 'Hoje, '.$diaHoje.' de '.$meses[$mesgetdate].' de '.$anoAtual.' ás '.$horaAgora.'';
    }

    public function getMenu(){
        $img_cat = '<img src="'.PATH.'image/arrow.png"';
        $pega_categorias = "SELECT * FROM 'loja_categorias' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $executar = self::conn()->prepare($pega_categorias);
        $executar->execute();
        if($executar->rowCount() == 0){}else{
            while($categoria = $executar->fetchObject()){
                echo '<li>'.$img_cat.'<a href="'.PATH.'/categoria/'.$categoria->slug.'">'.$categoria->titulo.'';

                $pega_subcategorias = "SELECT * FROM 'loja_subcategorias' WHERE id_cat = ? ";
                $executar_sub = self::conn()->prepare($pega_subcategorias);
                $executar_sub->execute(array($categoria->id));
                if($executar_sub->rowCount() == 0){echo '</li>';}else{
                    echo '<ul>';
                        while($subcategoria = $executar_sub->fechtObject()){
                            echo '<li><a href="'.PATH.'/categoria/'.$categoria->slug.'/'.$sub_categoria->slug.'">'.$sub_categoria->titulo.'</a></li>';
                    }
                    echo '</ul></li>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>`
```

Comment: Realmente o que deseja fazer? Seja mais específico em sua pergunta para os especialistas poderem de ajudar, recomendo que depois que faça isso siga o tour do SOpt http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade o erro é de sintaxe do mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM 'loja_categorias' ORDER BY id DESC
```

No mysql não usamos apóstrofos (aspas simples) para selecionar tabelas e colunas aonde deveria ser o sinal de ` (acento grave ou backtick)

Arrume fazendo isto:

```
SELECT * FROM `loja_categorias` ORDER BY id DESC
```

E isto:

```
SELECT * FROM `loja_subcategorias` WHERE id_cat = ?
```

É altamente recomendável que estude a documentação do mysql:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

---

Mais um detalhe, aqui você escreveu errado `$executar_sub->fechtObject(` não é `fechtObject` o correto é `fecthObject`, corrija ele assim:

```
                echo '<ul>';
                    while($subcategoria = $executar_sub->fecthObject()){
                        echo '<li><a href="'.PATH.'/categoria/'.$categoria->slug.'/'.$sub_categoria->slug.'">'.$sub_categoria->titulo.'</a></li>';
                }
                echo '</ul></li>';
```

Recomendo leia a documentação também:

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdostatement.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchobject.php